# Change of boarding station

Tags: irctc

What if I change my boarding station? Will it affect my RAC status? I booked an online ticket from KCVL to CDG RAC84 and the current status is RAC50. What if I change my boarding station to Mumbai will that affect my RAC status?
What should I do now? I booked ticket of 12217. I will board from vasai. Tickets are not available from vasai thats why I book from kcvl. Should I change boarding point now? On ticket it shows boarding point kcvl.